# Episerver MVC adding blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I have created episerver cms Block called "JumbortonBlock" using the template "BlockType" on the visual studio episerver extension. Then I run the solution, logged in as administrator and tried to create block from the editor. Then I see   block looks like below image.

[image: Episerver Block on editor page]

I could not see the button "Create" to create the block. Can any one help me to see the "Create" button on the episerver editor?

Comment: You are probably looking for the publish button in the top right corner

Comment: I am looking the "create" button of the block creation. I see the create button on the Alloy sample site. I am trying to see the same "create" button on my new site.

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot shows that you have already created the block, so your option at this point is to *publish* it using the `Publish` button.

This might be because you only have a single block type, meaning you don't have to select which block type to create - hence no `Create` button.

If you create a *second* block type, you will be prompted to select which block type to create.